# How to load 16-bit executables (NE) for resources?

Tags: winapi, loadlibrary

Is it possible to open a 16-bit Windows executable, just to browse its resources? I want to use `LoadLibraryEx` with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE`, so there is no worry about incompatibility with 64-bit processor, but it is still rejected, saying that it must be a valid Win32 executable. What was the function used to load 16-bit executables then?

Comment: I'm not aware of an API that would allow you to map an [NE image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Executable) from a 32-/64-bit process into memory (other than reading/mapping the raw file). If there is, it still [wouldn't be possible to extract resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/cc462815(v=msdn.10)). It looks like you're going to have to write your own NE image parser.

Comment: the quickest route might be to use 16-bit code (32-bit os) or an older OS version to extract the resources

Comment: @Remko I thought about that, but I want to make an application that can perform this. Maybe [this](https://github.com/otya128/winevdm) could be useful.

Comment: [Q65122: Executable-File Header Format](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/065/Q65122/). That's the original NE file format specification published by Microsoft. It looks to be sufficiently complete to derive a parser implementation.

Answer (score 0):

16-bit NE images cannot be loaded nor (directly) executed by 32-bit or 64-bit PE threads. You have to load such a file using ReadFile() or similar and dissect yourself. Despite that RC files are mostly compatible, 16-bit resources are completely differently organized than 32-bit resources. Most notably, there is no language subdirectory level.